# How to add share buttons in magento CMS pages?

Tags: magento

I have created CMS pages in Magento and I want to share with Social site using share buttons Facebook, Twitter, Google+ so any one to tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this part to :

```
your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

before this line --> `<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-c297c92f-9661-1cf3-697d-47c19ab7e281"});</script>
```

Add this part to your cms page :

```
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_hcount' displayText='Google +'></span>
```

**NOTE:** using sharethis extension

Comment: Glad to help you.If this solved your problem ,don't forget to add a tick (approve) the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check below URL for Addthis button, select style of button you want to share, grab the code and add that code to Magento Admin >> CMS  >> Pages. click on to Html view of Editor and paste the code which you have grab from Addthis site, and you will see share buttons on front end. Another method is you can add this code to your template file commonly used for Example 1column.phtml is used for CMS pages and you need Share buttons on all CMS pages then you can paste the same code in .phtml template file.

Add this : https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.UK8_PoafHcc

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread i would like to share my answer which i found.

1. Add a meta tag in

**template/page/html/head.phtml**

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="yoursite.com"/>
```

2. Create a Custom Variable from **System/Custom Variables** by pasting the Facebook sharing button code to **Variable HTML Value**.
3. To add like/share button to cms or static block, use the “Insert Variable” button to insert the Custom Variable you have just created.